# Indexing a list returned by a subroutine - Syntax

Tags: perl, syntax

Given I have the following incorrect code:

```
my $this_is_easier = caller(0)[0];
```

Why is it necessary for me to do the following in order to compile?

```
my $this_is_easier = (caller(0))[0];
```

Is this just a nuance of Perl's parser? In other languages like Python and C++ it's assumed that the function will return something indexable.

Comment: Easier still: `my ($this_is_easier) = caller(0)`

Comment: I know it's easier but I'm asking in terms of syntax. The original usage was say caller(0)[0]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `[]` follows another index, it implies a dereference.

```
$foo[...][...]   means   $foo[...]->[...]
```

When `()` follows another index, it implies a dereference.

```
$foo[...](...)   means   $foo[...]->(...)
```

As such, it's very reasonable for people to expect

```
foo(...)[...]
```

to mean

```
foo(...)->[...]
```

rather than

```
( foo(...) )[0]
```

That divergence in expectations is probably the reason it's not supported.

Comment: But does foo(...)[...] actually work? When I run that with foo returning a reference, it's still a syntax error.

Comment: huh? Why do you ask if it works? Your question asked why it doesn't work, and I explained why it doesn't.

Comment: sorry for the confusion. I thought you implied that foo(...)[...] should be interpreted as foo(...)->[...]. Didn't fully take in your last sentence.

Comment: I did. It should mean `foo(...)->[...]`. It should also mean `( foo(...) )[...]`. That's the problem.